# Two pages with same html render differently

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a page you can visit here:

http://beerportfolio.com/beerPortfolio2.php?u=hoppy

on the page is a slider which clears my div and loads new data into it. When I click the slider back its supposed to load the same data that was their originally. It does this but formats it all wrong when I go back to the original page.

On Original Page load:

[image]

then after clicking the slider and coming back:

[image]

The odd thing is when I looked at the html source of each page, they both looked exactly the same to me.

I am accomplishing all this with a js function that uses jquery load to call a php script to load each new page into the divs.

Comment: and if javascript disabled?  have pages been run through w3c validator? Compare 2 pages css and live html in browser console at elment level to see what might be happening

Comment: can you explain how do you get into the second image? I've clicked on the thumbnail, and press back, but everything is good.

Comment: it's not the same. before, #beerPortfolio is included inside of .row . after the slider, .row is empty, and #beerPortfolio is outside of it.

Comment: the html source is what's sent from the server at the time the page was loaded. any changes you make via javascript after the fact are **NOT** reflected in the source. you need to use a dom inspector to view the "live" source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is not exactly the same before and after.

Use something like Chrome Developer tools and inspect the elements instead of viewing the source. Usually the result of "view source" does not get updated when the page changes via Javascript.

Before:

```
<div id="beerPortfolio">
 <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div id="drop1">        <select id="dropOneMike" onchange="getDrop2Mike(5)">            <option value="0">All</option>
                            <option value="1">Alphabetical</option>
                            <option value="2">Brewery</option>
                            <option value="4">Rating</option>
                            <option value="3">Style</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div id="drop2">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="span3">

                </div>


            </div>
            <br>
```

After:

```
<div id="beerPortfolio">        <select id="dropOneMike" onchange="getDrop2Mike(5)">            <option value="0">All</option>
                            <option value="1">Alphabetical</option>
                            <option value="2">Brewery</option>
                            <option value="4">Rating</option>
                            <option value="3">Style</option>

                        </select>


                <div class="span3">
                    <div id="drop2">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="span3">

                </div>



            <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading the content in with JavaScript using the toggle, you are NOT loading in the identical HTML. You can tell by using Google Chrome's inspect element. Just right click on the item you want to know details about and click "Inspect Element". When you click "View Source" it's going to show you html that is unaffected by JavaScript.

When the page is initially rendered your  menu is in . When you toggle back, it is no longer there.